# Backbone.js: POST request with empty value

Tags: post, backbone.js, http-post

I am trying to make a POST request.
Here my code:

```
        var myModel = new MydModel({
            content: "ciao" 
        });
        console.log(myModel.get("content")); // "ciao"
        myModel.save();
```

If I look to the network activity it looks like this:

The response part `{id:0, content:"", ……}`

In the header part: `Request Payload {"content":"ciao"}`

Here my model:

```
define([], function () {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        url: function url ()  
        {
            return "http://localhost/users";
        }
    });

    return MyModel;
});
```

Is it my problem or is it in the server part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**send/receive vs request/response**

- a server receives requests and sends responses
- a client sends requests and receives responses

**in short**

- if `{id:0, content:"", ……}` (the response) is wrong, it's your server
- if `{"content":"asdasdsa"}` (the request) is wrong, it's your client

Comment: Sorry I would say my payload is `{"content":"ciao"}` as in myModel.get("content"). Said that, can I be sure that the problem is in the server part? thanks.

Comment: If the model really is only the code you posted, yes, it’s a server problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is little problem with receiving JSON-payload that "Backbone-client" sends to your Apache-server.

All you need to do is to manually parse JSON-payload from input on the server side ("php://input", for PHP), like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  
  $postStr = file_get_contents("php://input");
  //json_decode throws error or returns null if input is invalid json
  try {
    $json = json_decode($postStr, true);
    if(empty($json)) { 
      throw new Exception("Not valid json");
    }

  //must not be json, try query str instead 
  } catch(Errfor $e) { 
    $postVars = parse_str($postStr);
    foreach($postVars as $key=>$data) {
      $_POST[$key] = $data;
    }
  }
}
```

Full explanation you can find here:
http://colinbookman.com/2014/04/08/php-puts-posts-and-backbone-js/